# fetching wikidata labels in other languages from reconciled column

Tags: openrefine, wikidata-api

I want to use wikidata reconciliation to translate a column of terms into various languages by fetching the labels in those languages. Using SPARQL, I'd filter a query for label by language (this is the approach suggested in various similar cases). I don't see how to do the same using OpenRefine reconciliation, however.

[image]

Maybe the problem is that the wikidata API is language-specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say that you want to fetch labels in Italian, which has language code `it`. You can do that by entering `Lit` in the property input. You can also fetch descriptions with `Dit` or aliases with `Ait`. To fetch these terms in other languages, replace `it` by other language codes.

This is only documented at https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Reconciliation so far - I acknowledge that we need a more visible documentation for this (ideally it should be easily accessible from OpenRefine's user interface, given that the reconciliation service comes preconfigured in OpenRefine).

Comment: where do I add this "property input" @pintoch? I started writing "Les" [for labels in Spanish] in the "Add property" box as shown in @Will Hanley's image above, but I only got "SPARQL: Les" as a suggestion and that led me to an error

Comment: Just wanted to report that selecting SPARQL: Les seems to give the correct result at the moment.